# Spotfire Checkbox Filter Item Count

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filter, count, spotfire

I have a checkbox filter in a text area for a column named "Critical Activities". I have an action control button where I need to be able to count how many boxes are checked in this filter.

I cannot seem to correctly reference this filter and count how many of the boxes are checked.

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean you have an action control button where you need to count how many boxes are checked? Like you want to display that number in the text area? Use it in ironpython script? Use it in data function?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I just meant that I would like to use an ironpython script to do so, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is an ironpython solution. It will not work if there are commas in your values that you can filter by or two different tables share the same column name that you are interested in the checkbox count of (though I'm sure there is a way around this).

It finds the filter name you are interested in, puts the contents of that filter into a string, and then counts the number of commas that are separating each item in the filter and adds +1.

```
CurPanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel
CurPanel.InteractiveSearchPattern = "status:m"

# Column name you are interested in
filterName = "CheckboxFilterColumnName"
filterNameLength = len(filterName)
filterString = ""

for filters in CurPanel.FiltersMatchingSearchPattern:
    if(filters.FilterReference.ToString()[:filterNameLength] == filterName):
        filterString = filters.FilterReference.ToString()[(filterNameLength + 1):]
    break

# Number of filters that are checked based on csv
checkedFilters = filterString.count(',') + 1
```